VSCode cpp_properties.json didn't work but workspace works
enter image description heremy structure is this and I tried to add path in .vscode/cpp_properties.json like this  enter image description herehowever the ide can't find the header file also, so I created a workspace and edit it enter image description here and this time it wiped out .seems like cpp_properties.json is spare ,but copilot told me that it's local but in my files seems didn't work,why?
some reasons and the details about the local and the global settings

If you're using the cmake plugin it should configure intellisense for you, you should just remove cpp_properties.json

that's right,thank you!
